# How to access data sent by node sever using client side javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf.js

I am using a node sever to send a table from a sqlite db to the browser. This table contains filename and path of a pdf file that I want to render on the browser. Until now I was using hard coded paths for the the pdf file and rendering. But now i have setup a get route and a controller in node such that whenever '/content' is hit in browser , the server queries the database and and sends the data to the client. To the send the data I am using

```
res.render('content/index',{data:queryData});
```

Now, how do I access this data using client side javascript so that I can pass the path of the pdf file to the function that renders the pdf? I have done research and the nearest answer I got was using XMLHttpRequest. I tried this method

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const path = "http://localhost:3000/content";
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
{
   var myResponseText = xhr.responseText;
   console.log(myResponseText);
}
};
xhr.open('get', path, true);
xhr.send();
```

When I do this I get the entire html code for the view. Not the data I expected.  How do I solve this issue. I have done some more reading while writing this post and I suppose. I have set a header somewhere? But the documentation says

```
app.render(view, [locals], callback)
```

which means res.render can take local variables, shouldn't be setting the headers?

Comment: What is your "function that renders the pdf" Is it an entirely client-side javascript that manipulates the DOM? Or is it server-side?

Comment: XHR is meant to receive data from server by a fully-loaded client-side page running javascript (XHR is client-side javascript). If you're using XHR you'd want to do some DOM manipulation to insert the data into the HTML.

Comment: @laggingreflex I am using pdf.js. It is client side js plugin, It renders the pdf into a canvas. It needs canvas id and path of the pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

You should return json instead of render template:

```
app.get('content/index', (req, res) => {
  res.json({data: queryData});
});
```

Comment: but I also need to render the page. Doing this only sends the data but doesn't render the page.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using pdf.js

PDF.js needs the PDF file, e.g.:

```
pdfjsLib.getDocument('helloworld.pdf')
```

I'm assuming your `queryData` goes something like this:

```
{ filename: 'file.pdf', path: './path/to/file.pdf' }
```

I'm not sure what's in your `content/index` or what path this is on, but you obviously need to find a way to make your PDF file ('./path/to/file.pdf') available (as a download). See [Express's built-in static server](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) or [res.download()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download) to do that.

Once you have the PDF file available as a download, plug that path into PDF.js's `.getDocument('/content/file.pdf')` and do the rest to render the PDF onto the canvas or whatever.

Hope that helps.